# Sincronizar agenda del telefono con mi app

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, content-provider

alguien por favor me ayudaria con lo que seria la sincronizacion de los contactos del movil con mi aplicacion? Logro obtenerlos mediante un codigo, pero resulta que salen repetidos, por lo que veo esto se da por whatsapp, etc. Porque pruebo en otro dispositivo que no tiene instalado whatsapp u otros similares estos contactos no se repiten...
el codigo con lo que hago esto es:

```
public void ObtenerDatos() {

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas telefónicas.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para realizar llamadas!");
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Se tiene permiso

            String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    projeccion,
                    selectionClause,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

            txtnombre.setText("");

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                txtnombre.append(" Nombre: " + c.getString(0) + " Número: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
            }
            c.close();

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        // No se necesita requerir permiso OS menos a 6.0.
    }
}
```

como dije funciona bien, solo que cuando existe whatsapp, telegram u otro servicio parecido salen repetidos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo lo que comentas Wilson, tu código es perfecto, obtienes los registros de números telefónicos en un cursor:

```
  String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    projeccion,
                    selectionClause,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);
```

pero aquí el problema es que el registro que tienes de uno o varios teléfonos de un mismo contacto es en realidad diferente, como ejemplo el numero telefónico de este usuario:

```
Cajamarca +593 96 058 7465
Cajamarca +593960587465
Cajamarca 0960587465
```

en realidad son "diferentes".

Una solución es agregar a la proyección el numero telefónico normalizado:
[ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookupColumns.html#NORMALIZED_NUMBER)

de esta forma:

```
String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER};
```

al leer este numero puedes verificar si el número normalizado se encuentra en la lista para evitar agregarlo:

```
 ...
 ...

           String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER};
            String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    projeccion,
                    selectionClause,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

            txtnombre.setText("");

                HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();
                int indexOfNormalizedNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER);
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    String normalizedNumber = c.getString(indexOfNormalizedNumber);
                    if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)) {

                        //*No se encuentra numero, lo agrega.
                        txtnombre.append(" Nombre: " + c.getString(0) + " Número: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");


                    }
                }
                c.close();
   ...
   ...
```

De esta forma evitaras mostrar números telefonicos repetidos.

Comment: Bueno esta respuesta me funciono muy bien, gracias por ese aspecto, pero quisiera preguntar una ultima cosa, sabe tal ves como obtener también el correo de los contactos??

Comment: Usa String email = c.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

Comment: Ya intente hacerlo con eso anteriormente pero me muestra el numero de celular mas no el email... probe tambien con todos los Data1,Data2,... ninguno me da la direccion...
PD: mis contactos si cuentan con email...

Comment: Si deseas mejor agrega otra respuesta  con el código que tienes hasta ahora  pero ahora requiriendo el email y te ayudo, saludos!

Comment: Siento que ud puede ayudarme con con esta pregunta que me esta desesperando... [https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/243833/6795]

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la variable del `if` y el `while` por que al parecer en uno te llena el valor con `" Nombre: " + c.getString(0) + " Número: " + c.getString(1) + "\n"` dando al parecer cabida al tamaño del número, pero luego en el  `txtnombre.setText("");` te cierra los espacios y lo toma como un campo diferente ya que ambas cumplen con los requerimientos del `if` y el `while`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Se tiene permiso

        String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    projeccion,
                    selectionClause,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

        xtnombre.setText("");

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            txtnombre.append(" Nombre: " + c.getString(0) + " Número: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
        }
        c.close();

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
```